react-native-pell-rich-editor: I am trying to set urls that are typed in the editor to be converted to anchor tags
Using this editor I have managed to set the URLs in the editor text to colour red and underlined as anchor tags. But when I use setContentHTML() the cursor jumps or goes back to the start of the editor.
This is my code:
const regExp = /((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g;

  
  const editorOnChange = (txt) => {
    embeddedString = txt.replace(regExp, "<a style='text-decoration:underline;color:red;' href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    console.log(embeddedString);
    
    richText.current?.setContentHTML(embeddedString);

  }

<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}   style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                <RichEditor style={{ flex: 1, }}
                
                placeholder="Enter Comment..."
                    ref={richText}
                    //initialContentHTML={editorHtml }
                    onChange={ (txt)=> {editorOnChange(txt)}}
                />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

How would the editor be able to keeps its cursor position while the user types rather than the cursor jumping to the start when the user types?
